# Access denied when attempting to remove printer

Tags: python, printing, pycharm, pywin32

```
def on_printer_button_clicked(self, button):
    for i in range(len(self.printer_buttons)):
        if button == self.printer_buttons[i]:
            pHandle = win32print.OpenPrinter(self.printers[i]['pPrinterName'])
    win32print.DeletePrinter(pHandle)
    return
```

So all I'm doing is opening the printer handle and calling the function Delete Printer, as you can see.  Here's what I get in the console when I run the function:

```
uninstall_windowGUI.py", line 57, in on_printer_button_clicked
win32print.DeletePrinter(pHandle)
pywintypes.error: (5, 'DeletePrinter', 'Access is denied.')
```

I've tried running the IDE (Pycharm in Administrator mode, and still get the same issue.  Any idea on how to move on?  I'm kind of stuck until I can figure this out.  (Also:  I'm using Gtk and Gdk to create the interface, if that makes a differece.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation states that *Printer handle must be opened for PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER*. Something like this might work:

```
PRINTER_DEFAULTS = {"DesiredAccess":win32print.PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER} 
win32print.OpenPrinter(self.printers[i]['pPrinterName'], PRINTER_DEFAULTS)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a ton.  I actually had to replace PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER to PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS, because for whatever reason I still was getting the "Access denied".